# Primefaces Picklist not saving on server

Tags: jsf, primefaces

This is working fine locally and working intermittently on the server. No errors so very hard to debug.

I have a picklist

```
 <p:pickList id="pickListInput"  converter="entityConverter" value="#{GuideViewAdminController.gameTaskHotspots}" var="hotspot" itemLabel="#{hotspot.title}" itemValue="#{hotspot}" />
```

That is saving to the backing bean when the modal pop up it's in closes, via a remote command.

```
 <p:remoteCommand name="saveGameTask" update=":tabView:taskList" onsuccess="delayedRefreshData()" actionListener="#{GuideViewAdminController.saveSelectedTask()}" />
```

The backing bean converts the output into something I can use

```
 String input = new Gson().toJson(gameTaskHotspots.getTarget());
        if(input != null && !input.equals(selectedTask.input))
            selectedTask.input = input;

    String output = new Gson().toJson(gameTaskHotspotsToShow.getTarget());
        if(output != null && !output.equals(selectedTask.output))
            selectedTask.output = output;
```

Like I said - this works 100% of the time locally - and sometimes on the server. Can anyone see anything in here that might interupt the flow on the server?

Comment: can you show the code for delayedRefreshData()? means which backing bean method does it call?

Comment: Sounds like a broken converter and/or `equals()`. Hard to tell without a MCVE. Make sure you don't miss faces messages or warnings in server log.

Comment: You can also search for errors in console (`F12`) -> post request -> response.

Comment: Thanks I'm not getting any errors in the server log or in console. Which is painful. I'll update the question with the server log and I've got rid of the equals. It's all fine locally and on a test host, just not on the live host. I'm wondering now if the model window closing is losing the data in the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently had the same issue with my PickList component. I realized that it's because you're using a JSON converter (in this case gson) in order to convert your value objects.I don't know why but some how the returned string value is 
not the same with what you have converted in your "::getAsString" method. So I suggest changing your converter strategy.